# Vue App calling api hosted on Nginx keeps trying to reach localhost

Tags: vue.js, nginx, .net-6.0

I have a Vue app that is hosted on Nginx. The API is on a separate Server. Whenever I host the API locally it works locally but when I browse the website from a different PC the website is always looking for "localhost" as the API even when I hard code the IP address in.

I feel like I must be super close, the firewall has all allowed ports and I also tested with it off.

Vue Page

```
    const updateOthers = async () => {
        try {
            //const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:7031/api/Home/CallOthers');
            const response = await axios.get('http://10.20.55.17:5025/Home/CallOthers');
            /*const response = await axios.get('http://10.20.55.17/Home/CallOthers');*/
            ////const response = await axios.get('http://10.20.55.38:5025/Home/CallOthers');
            //const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5025/Home/CallOthers');
            //const response = await axios.get('http://10.20.210.90:5025/Home/CallOthers');

            console.log("Others - " + response.data)
            others.value = response.data;

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
```

API

```
        [HttpGet]
        //[EnableCors("allows")]
        [EnableCors]
        [Route("CallOthers")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CallOthers()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("B4 Others");

                _logger.LogInformation(connection);
                var count = await SQLCalls.CallProcedureAsync(connection, "dbo.spTowerShipments_OtherSeries");
                _logger.LogInformation(count.ToString());
                return Ok(count);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { _logger.LogError(ex.Message); }

            return BadRequest("Not Found");
        }
```

NGINX

```
server_name _;
        charset utf-8;

        location /home {
                root /var/www/parts5;
                proxy_pass http://10.20.55.17:5025;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
#               proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location / {
                root /var/www/parts5/wwwroot;

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html  =404;

        }
```

Comment: 10.x.x.x are private IP addresses.  Are you trying to reach the API from the internet or across a local network?  You may want to try axios.get() with a public IP address

Comment: API is on the local network. on a side note I can use curl from a different pc and successfully call the API and get the data I want. For some reason only with Vue App im not able to